# Modelling outcome variable with lognormal distribution

Tags: regression, data-transformation

I have an outcome variable with a distribution as follows, and I need to do some regression modelling. I know that often such variables are transformed to get a normal distribution.

However, it would be really important to do the final interpretation in the original scale of the outcome variable. What are my options?

My own thoughts:

1. log-transforming the variable, doing modelling, and later back-transforming the results using exp()
2. are there packages with allow to model this variable with its original scale using link functions?

[image]

Comment: Yes and yes. You can log transform the variable, back transforming the predictions, and/or run the model using software that allows specification of a distribution link function. The choice is up to you as the analyst and there is little or nothing lost using either approach. Why not run both and compare the results as an educational exercise?

Comment: Thanks. Could you name some R packages that allow using lognormal link function?

Comment: There seem to be several modules for *Generalized Linear Models* in R which offer link functions.

Comment: You have given very little context. Start with the `glm` function (in the defaukt `stats` package). You could start with `glm(y ~ ..., family=quasi(lin="log"), data=your_data_frame, ...)`